# Moving an application from a hidden screen to another in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I often encounter situations where one display of my Windows 10 dual screen setup is unavailable for some reason. Either the display is closed or it is displaying a full screen game or the display might be showing picture from another computer or a gaming console. Is there some convenient way to move a window from the hidden display to the visible display without having to blindly grab its title bar with the mouse cursor?

Comment: Click on the taskbar to give it focus.  Use [Win] + arrows to move it to the current display.  Practice when both screens are functional.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Please expand your comment into an answer, so that cyberixae can mark it as the accepted answer (since it appears that it worked for him).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  Click on the taskbar to give it focus. You can also use [ALT]-[TAB] to select the application.

2)  Use [Win] + arrows to move it to the current display.

In older versions of Windows where this option does not exist, instead of [Win] + arrows, use [ALT]-[Space] to get the system menu.  Select "move" from the system menu.  Use the arrow keys to move the window at least one pixel.  Use the mouse to move the window into view.

Pro tip! -- Practice when both screens are functional.